# Simplest way to determine if the user has internet connection? Navigation.onLine doesn't work since it always returns true on some OS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that tells me if the user currently has internet connection. The first thing that came to mind was to use `navigation.onLine`, however, it turned out that on Windows 11 and Linux with Chrome, it always returns true, so this is unusable.

My second idea is to make a GET request to some resource and assume that the user has no connection if the request fails, but that seems very crude to me.

Do I have any other alternatives?

Comment: For what purpose do you want to know that? I’d assume usually it’s to know whether you *could* reach some specific resource, and in that case the best way is probably simply to try…?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a GET request and if that request is successful do something, while if that request times out, do something else.

It is advisable to request to the same domain that's opened or which accepts requests.

EDIT

As @Corey Ogburn pointed out in the comment section, a HEAD request is better in terms of performance than a GET request.

Comment: A HEAD request would be more performant. HEAD is like GET except it doesn't contain the body. The response should still contain all the same headers as if you made a GET though.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn thanks for pointing that out, edited my answer to reflect that.